# Multi dimensional inputs in pytorch Linear method?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, perceptron

When building a simple perceptron neural network we usuall passes a 2D matrix of input of format `(batch_size,features)` to a 2D weight matrix, similar to this simple neural network in [numpy](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/). I always assumed a Perceptron/Dense/Linear layer of a neural network only accepts an input of 2D format and outputs another 2D output. But recently I came across this pytorch model in which a Linear layer accepts a 3D input tensor and output another 3D tensor (`o1 = self.a1(x)`).

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.a1 = nn.Linear(4,4)
        self.a2 = nn.Linear(4,4)
        self.a3 = nn.Linear(9,1)
    def forward(self,x):
        o1 = self.a1(x)
        o2 = self.a2(x).transpose(1,2)
        output = torch.bmm(o1,o2)
        output = output.view(len(x),9)
        output = self.a3(output)
        return output

x = torch.randn(10,3,4)
y = torch.ones(10,1)

net = Net()

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters())

for i in range(10):
    net.zero_grad()
    output = net(x)
    loss = criterion(output,y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print(loss.item())
```

These are the question I have,

1. Is the above neural network a valid one? that is whether the model will train correctly?
2. Even after passing a 3D input `x = torch.randn(10,3,4)`, why is the pytorch `nn.Linear` doesn't shows any error and gives a 3D output?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Newer versions of PyTorch allows [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#linear) to accept N-D input tensor, the only constraint is that the last dimension of the input tensor will equal `in_features` of the linear layer. The linear transformation is then applied on the last dimension of the tensor.
For instance, if `in_features=5` and `out_features=10` and the input tensor `x` has dimensions 2-3-5, then the output tensor will have dimensions 2-3-10.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a look at the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#linear), you will find that indeed the `Linear` layer accepts tensors of arbitrary shape, where only the last dimension must match with the `in_features` argument you specified in the constructor.

The output will have exactly the same shape as the input, only the last dimension will change to whatever you specified as `out_features` in the constructor.

It works in a way that the same layer (with the same weights) is applied on each of the (possibly) multiple inputs. In your example you have an input shape of `(10, 3, 4)` which is basically a set of `10 * 3 == 30` 4-dimensional vectors. So, your layers `a1` and `a2` are applied on all of these 30 vectors to generate another `10 * 3 == 30` 4D vectors as the output (because you specified `out_features=4` in the constructor).

So, to answer your questions:

> Is the above neural network a valid one? that is whether the model will train correctly?

Yes, it is valid and it will be trained "correctly" from a technical pov. But, as with any other network, if this will actually correctly tackle your problem is another question.

> Even after passing a 3D input x = torch.randn(10,3,4), why is the pytorch nn.Linear doesn't shows any error and gives a 3D output?

Well, because it is defined to work this way.

Comment: Interesting! Could you please explain the part where you mention " input shape of (10, 3, 4) which is basically a set of 10 * 3 == 30 4-dimensional vectors". Having difficulty visualizing this. @sebrockm

Comment: @SohamBhaumik There are many ways to think about this: e.g. a shape of (10, 3) can be seen as 10 3d-vectors. It can also be seen as a 10x3 matrix of numbers. Combine these two ways of thinking and now a shape of (10, 3, 4) can be seen as a 10x3 matrix, where each entry is not a number but a 4d-vector. So, you have 30 4d-vectors.

Comment: Ah! the reshape function has never made so much sense! Im starting out with Machine Learning and am having a super tough time visualizing dimensionalities, and shapes and how interpretations of pytorch tensors are all use-case based. thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question too.
Thank you, everyone.
I tested it.

First, do this...

```
torch.manual_seed(0)

a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 2, 2).astype(np.float32)
a = torch.from_numpy(a)

b = torch.nn.Linear(2, 3, bias=False)
torch.nn.init.normal_(b.weight, mean=0, std=1.0)
for param in b.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

c = b(a)

print('a =\n', a)
print()
print('b.weight =\n', b.weight)
print()
print('c =\n', c)
```

↓

```
a =
 tensor([[[ 0.,  1.],
         [ 2.,  3.]],

        [[ 4.,  5.],
         [ 6.,  7.]],

        [[ 8.,  9.],
         [10., 11.]]])

b.weight =
 Parameter containing:
tensor([[ 1.2645, -0.6874],
        [ 0.1604, -0.6065],
        [-0.7831,  1.0622]])

c =
 tensor([[[-0.6874, -0.6065,  1.0622],
         [ 0.4666, -1.4986,  1.6204]],

        [[ 1.6207, -2.3907,  2.1786],
         [ 2.7748, -3.2829,  2.7368]],

        [[ 3.9288, -4.1750,  3.2950],
         [ 5.0829, -5.0672,  3.8532]]])
```

Next, do this...

```
b_ = b.weight.clone().detach()

c_ = []

for a_ in a:
    c_.append(a_ @ b_.T)

c_ = torch.stack(c_)

print('a =\n', a)
print()
print('b_ =\n', b_)
print()
print('c_ =\n', c_)
```

↓

```
a =
 tensor([[[ 0.,  1.],
         [ 2.,  3.]],

        [[ 4.,  5.],
         [ 6.,  7.]],

        [[ 8.,  9.],
         [10., 11.]]])

b_ = 
 tensor([[ 1.2645, -0.6874],
        [ 0.1604, -0.6065],
        [-0.7831,  1.0622]])

c_ = 
 tensor([[[-0.6874, -0.6065,  1.0622],
         [ 0.4666, -1.4986,  1.6204]],

        [[ 1.6207, -2.3907,  2.1786],
         [ 2.7748, -3.2829,  2.7368]],

        [[ 3.9288, -4.1750,  3.2950],
         [ 5.0829, -5.0672,  3.8532]]])
```

Finally, check...

```
print('diff =', torch.mean(torch.abs(c - c_)))
```

↓

```
diff = tensor(0.)
```

That's all.

Even if you change 3D:`a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 2, 2).astype(np.float32)` to 4D:`a = np.arange(60).reshape(5, 3, 2, 2).astype(np.float32)`, diff will be zero.

Interesring! :-D